# How can I attach unencoded "&" character in my RestSharp API request

Tags: c#, wordpress, rest, woocommerce, restsharp

I am trying connect a wordpress Woocommerce store though the API. The authentication process requires literal "&" Character but RestSharp keeps encoding them to "%26" which is not quite what I want.

Comment: possibly you already tried this, but have you tried doubling it like this >>  `&&` instead of `&`  ?

Comment: Tried it but didn't work, instead I got "%26%26"

Comment: was worth a shot  :)  ... I presume the issue is client side ? --  could you post code as to how you are forming the request. after reading the docs, I see no reason why something like `request.AddParameter("name", "my&value")` would fail.  barring that could always try the enforce string method,  eg   @"my&value"     :)

Comment: If using PHP could you use [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)? If not using PHP, there must be something similar in other languages.

Comment: Please post your code.